# Rails 4 - routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 app.

The routes.rb file has a root file as follows:

```
 root :to => "home#index"
```

I have a home_controller.rb as follows:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
# def index
# 
# end
end
```

I have a view called index.html.erb in a folder called home.

When I start my rails server (localhost:3000). I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Any advice? I thought this was supposed to be a really simple setup. I can't see what I've done wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: can you please include the whole error, including the file and line number? Then include the file where it claims to be?

Comment: Why did you comment out your index action? You want to point to an action that is no longer available.

Comment: Hi,  the whole text of the error is: SyntaxError at /
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Comment: Hi, I commented the index action because the default is to go to index without an express action for that step.

Comment: You shouldn't comment it out. There are very few cases where you want to keep commented out code. Anyway, we need to see the file where the error points to. The problem is obvious, but we cannot help you without the file which errors out.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with routes particulary, there probably are too much of "end" keywords somewhere...

Comment: You would think the error is crystal clear in that matter. If we could only see the file the error is pointing to.. :)

Comment: Actually the error suggests the opposite: he has an end where it should not be.

Comment: I'm afraid we can't tell much without seeing his files though.

Comment: Hi, which file would you need to see? I thought I had copied all the relevant parts of the code. I have uncommented the index action in the home controller but am getting the same error. Should I paste the entire routes.rb? Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't have to paste files here, the problem is simple - just check your files yourself (and start with routes.rb file) and find & remove an extra "end". But if you fail with finding this redundant keyword, then paste your routes.rb here, more eyes see more.